# Android app like Psion 3 database

Tags: android, information-management

In the olden days, the [Psion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psion_Series_3) had the ability to create your own little databases. I used these for anything from books by author to DIY projects.

I can't find anything similar for Android. There are 'notes' apps but they have no fields and no search facility, or at the other end of the scale, highly complicated 'manage a multinational corporation' things like Trello.

Does anyone know of an app along these lines?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! It's a bit hard to figure what *exactly* you're looking for (though one can get a "raw idea"). May I recommend you taking a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) and see if you can [edit] and improve your question? The clearer you describe your needs, the better potential answers can match that – which increases your chances for "useful answers" quite a bit :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use [Memento Database](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.luckydroid.droidbase); from its description on Play Store:

> Memento Database is a highly flexible and customizable database management tool. Created for anyone seeking to store various data on their Android devices, the software enables users to create custom libraries* with unique sets of data fields, quickly add new entries and, finally, share entries with friends or colleagues, or export them to other systems with just a few taps.
>   A proper database management tool is nothing without corresponding search, navigation and sorting tools. Memento Database has it all – and it even supports barcode scanning for searching the database!

I really like this application as it gives the user a degree of freedom and customization I rarely see on an Android app. One of the best things is that you can sync the databases you create with Google Sheets to have them available across all your devices.

* There are also presets for various kind of databases (books, movies, CDs, etc).

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this out. Looks promising, but a bit put off by the feedback - complaints about ads, especially having paid for the pro version and also something off putting about the licence key/unlocker.  Can you comment on either of these?

Comment: About the ads: they are just banners at the bottom of the page. There are no timed popus or videos like on other apps. Overall they are not annoying. About the pro version I can't say anything, haven't bought it (yet).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aSQLiteManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.andsen.asqlitemanager) to create a personal SQLite database on your Android device. Then you can save this data on SD card or Dropbox and so on.

The project page is on SourceForge: [Android SQLite Manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asqlitemanager/)

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try this too as I'd like to get an understanding of SQLite: the feedback suggests something of a learning curve for this app though. In its favour, is that it is Open Source and assume that the databases can be read externally if necessary and not tied into some proprietary system. Feedback suggests a problem with the 'commit' process.